# Production of “Green Hydrogen” by photosynthesis

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, photosynthesis

In a popular science book from the 1970s I read about experiments to tweak some microorganisms to produce elemental hydrogen by photosynthesis.

Is this a feasible way to produce “Green hydrogen”? What kind of microorganism can be used for this task, and what is the efficiency of that process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Photosynthesis**

The aspects of photosynthesis pertinent to this question are as follows:

The overall chemical transformation in the light reactions of photosynthesis is:

> 2H<sub>2</sub>O + hν → 4H<sup>+</sup> + 4e<sup>–</sup> + O<sub>2</sub>

The hydrogen ions are produced in such a way as to create a gradient that is used to generate ATP, the electrons are used to reduce NADP<sup>+</sup> to NADPH. Together these allow the reductive synthesis of carbohydrate sugars from CO<sub>2</sub>.

This process involves two photosystems — PSII and PSI — shown below, the latter of which is most pertinent to this topic.

[image: Photosynthesis]

**Coupling Photosynthesis to Hydrogen Production**

The basic objective of modifying photosynthesis to generate hydrogen — *biophotoloysis* — involves using the electron to reduce the hydrogen ion to hydrogen gas, rather than allowing it to be used to oxidize NADP<sup>+</sup>.

> 2H<sup>+</sup> + 2e<sup>–</sup> → H<sub>2</sub>

So that the overall reaction becomes:

> 2H<sub>2</sub>O + hν → 2H<sub>2</sub> + O<sub>2</sub>

(Of course, this will be at the expense of energy and reducing power for carbohydrate synthesis.)

**Using Hydrogenase for the Catalysis**

The enzyme, [hydrogenase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogenase), can catalyse the reduction of hydrogen ions shown above. This enzyme is rare in eukaryotes and absent from higher plants. It is thought to be very ancient, and may have originally been involved in energy generation from hydrogen in early evolution. One of the roles it plays in contemporary organisms is in reoxidizing NADH generated during certain fermentations in bacteria such as the *Clostridium* family — hydrogen is the gas produced in gas gangrene caused by *Clostridium perfringens*.

Certain photosynthetic organisms — notably the microalga, *Chlamydomonas reinhardtii*, and the photosynthetic cyanobacteria — also contain a hydrogenase in their chloroplasts. The activity of this is generally low, but appears to be coupled to photosynthesis in certain circumstances. This is through the reduced ferredoxin produced at PSI transferring its electron to the iron or iron–nickel centre of the hydrogenase:

[image: biophotolysis]

The physiological importance of this coupling is not fully understood but its discovery offered the possibility of using it to produce hydrogen from water.

**Commercial Application — Approaches and Problems**

The focus of many of the attempts to exploit this coupling to produce hydrogen on a commercial scale have used *Chlamydomonas reinhardtii*, where is was shown that deprivation of sulphur enhanced the evolution of hydrogen significantly. From a commercial standpoint the price at which a fuel can be sold depends on the cost of its production, and to be viable this has to be competitive with alternatives. Hence it is important to maximize the production of hydrogen, and considerable effort has been directed towards this. However, we are not yet at a stage where photosynthetic hydrogen can compete with other fuels.

The two main factors limiting widespread commercial exploitation of this process have been the sensitivity of the dehydrogenase to inhibition by the oxygen produced in the process, and the low efficiencies of conversion of solar energy (<2%). The former problem is, in fact, one of the reasons for using *Chlamydomonas reinhardtii*, as it can perform oxidative respiration, lowering the concentration of oxygen. Attempts have been made — and are presumably still being made — to engineer the hydrogenase to reduce its sensitivity to oxygen, to control the oxygen concentration, and to improve the photosynthetic quantum yield by engineering PSII. Increasing the efficiency of photosynthesis itself is a more difficult problem in the eukaryote, *Chlamydomonas*, and efforts in this respected have mainly been directed at photosynthetic bacteria.

**Literature**

My knowledge of this field is based purely on a perusal of sources found in a literature search. I was actually surprised to discover that there is at least one journal dedicated to hydrogen as an energy source. Here are the papers I consulted:

[Bolatkhan *et al.* (2019) *Int. J. Hydrogen Energy* **44**, 5799–5811](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0360319919302241)
[Oh *et al.* (2013) Biohydrogen, Ch.3, pp. 45-65 Elsevier.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780444595553000039)
[Ni *et al.* (2006) *Fuel Processing Technology* **87**, 461–472](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378382005001980?casa_token=CPiJcHX-Q2MAAAAA:j3n6dFjfaez_PXOpVpTFvDiz3AaywBJx0-TNjAWSeNaK9FQbNi2ZeFX-JmdLmubC16w3NPbp)
[Hemschemeier, A. and Happe1, T. (2005) *Biochem. Soc. Trans.* **33**, 39-41](https://portlandpress.com/biochemsoctrans/article-abstract/33/1/39/65847/The-exceptional-photofermentative-hydrogen?redirectedFrom=PDF)